# service worker i want to pass fetch response to another fetch

Tags: json, service-worker

I want to fetch json data from first fetch want to pass same response data to 2nd fetch.

here is my code. i am very new in service worker.

## service_worker.js

```js
#service_worker.js

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);

var url = 'http://127.0.0.1/1/json.json';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET', // or 'PUT'
  //body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.then(response => console.log(response))
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => fetch('http://127.0.0.1/1/1.php', {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify({data: response}), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.text())
//.then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)))
//.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log(response))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't returning the response in the call where you log the first response.

```
.then(response => console.log(response))
```

As a result, you are passing `undefined` for `response` during `JSON.stringify({data: response})`. You'll want to update it to something similar to:

```
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return response;
})
```